# White screen 15.04 Lubuntu startup

Tags: lubuntu, startup, 15.04, white-screen

I am getting a white screen after startup in Lubuntu 15.04 and I do not know if this is by design or if it is a bug. It clears away from a mouse click to reveal the login window. It reminds me of the Windows 8.1 start screen which acts in a similar way, though I have no idea why it would be a white screen with mouse cursor - it just seems wrong.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I got this in Lubuntu 15.04. It appears to be an issue with `lightdm-gtk-greeter` 2.0.0:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mate/+bug/1426664

Unfortunately, the PPA for the fix in that post is not available anymore.

It appears to be available here:

https://launchpad.net/~lightdm-gtk-greeter-team/+archive/ubuntu/stable

The good news is that the fix is supposedly included in 15.10, which should be releaed in a few weeks.